# How to send html email through Azure Logic App and Outlook

Tags: azure, outlook, azure-logic-apps

I am using Azure Logic App to send Email via Outlook.

However, I could not use the [Send an Outlook Email] Action in HTML format.

The mail sent is in plain-text format.

How could I sent the HTML email with Azure Logic App and Send an Outlook Email ?

[image: Azure Logic App Image]

[image: Plain-Text Email Image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open the "Send Email" task and click on Advanced Options.  There is a "Is HTML" setting under there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have sent HTML emails successfully. :)

Answer (score 3):

This is all for V1 of the Action. for V2 this isn't possible anymore.

This blog explains new options: https://blog.sandro-pereira.com/2020/01/26/logic-apps-how-to-send-a-well-formatted-html-email-notification-with-office-365-outlook-connector/

Basically the workaround to have the HTMl render properly is to create a variable and paste the HTML in there and then reference that variable as the body of the email.

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Send an Email Action" and click on "Add new parameter" and then select "Is HTML" .
[image: 1stImage]

then set the value of parameter "Is HTML"  to "Yes" [image: image2]

Answer (score 0):

You can send an email with an HTML body with Outlook "Send an email (V2)" action by first initializing or setting a string variable to the HTML body you want and then setting the body to only that string variable.  Below is an example of what you should see:

[image]

I appreciate this information from Sandro Pereira, who posted it to his blob at https://blog.sandro-pereira.com/2020/01/26/logic-apps-how-to-send-a-well-formatted-html-email-notification-with-office-365-outlook-connector/