# Azure Logic Apps :: embed HTML image into email alert

Tags: html, azure, html-email, azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

I have a weekly newsletter which is sent by Azure Logic Apps and which body looks like follow:

[image]

As you can see I'm trying to add an image into the body of the e-mail:

`<img src="https://img.favpng.com/5/18/2/price-tag-icon-business-icon-price-icon-png-favpng-y4cauP3Vz2MfJXm8Fahz1tCeK.jpg">`

The problem is that I receive that like this:

[image]

So the HTML code is not interpreted.

Is there any way I can send the image embedded into the body of the e-mail?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send html email through Azure Logic App and Outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53027699/how-to-send-html-email-through-azure-logic-app-and-outlook)

Comment: Thank you @esqew but no, in the Gmail send email (V2) there are no HTML parameters in the Settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by myself than you to a [link](https://blog.sandro-pereira.com/2020/01/26/logic-apps-how-to-send-a-well-formatted-html-email-notification-with-office-365-outlook-connector/) provided by @esqew.

These were the steps:

1. Initialize a variable:

[image]

2. Set the variable:

[image]

```
<img src="https://img.favpng.com/5/18/2/price-tag-icon-business-icon-price-icon-png-favpng-y4cauP3Vz2MfJXm8Fahz1tCeK.jpg" alt="Price Tag Icon Business Icon Price Icon, PNG, 1214x1234px, Price Tag Icon, Azure, Blue, Business Icon, Cobalt Blue Download Free" width="100" height="100", style="float:left;padding-right: 30px;">
```

3. Insert into the body:

[image]